# How to properly use any Java API

Tags: java, eclipse, api

I have been trying to use the vget library/api to make my own youtube video downloader. The vget library can be found here: https://github.com/axet/vget

I have downloaded the zip on github and I imported the project into eclipse. However, I am confused to how I am supposed to properly use this API. Should I make a completely new project, and import the classes that I need or do I put my own source files in the project of the api?

I have read other threads concerning this problem. However, they all mention how a api is typically packaged in a JAR file, but in my case it is just files and classes. So I am confused to how I should properly use this api.

Comment: Most likely, you want to create your project, and then add the jar file for the external library to your classpath. This varies by IDE, so you will want to check to see how to do that in Eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The vget project is a maven project. You can see that because it has a `pom.xml` file in the root folder of the project.

To use it, you don't even need to download the source, because the compiled jar files are already stored in the central maven repository. You can find more information about this here:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.axet/vget/1.1.23

(in general, you can use the http://mvnrepository.com/ site to search whether your library is available on the maven central repository. If it's even a mildly popular library, then chances are that it is)

What you need to do is to make your own project a maven project.
[Here's a "5 minutes" starter guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) that describes how to do that.

When you've done that, you just add the dependency on vget to your pom.xml file in the `<dependencies>` section:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
    <artifactId>vget</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.23</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: so now that I got that all set up, all i need to do is import the classes I need right?

Comment: If you do a "maven install" or "maven package" on the command line, maven will download the jar files for you to your local repository and put them on the classpath while you compile. Modern versions of Eclipse also support maven builds, you only need to check whether your maven settings in the preferences are correct, and in some cases you may need to do a "Update Maven Project" after you change the pom.xml

Answer (score 0):

Since you are *making use* of a 3rd party software, and not *extending it* with your own logic, the way to go is to create a new project, which references the 3rd party software.

You then construct your application and make it do whatever you need it to do. When it comes to using logic which is available within the 3rd party logic, you would then simply delegate that call to the 3rd party library.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen on the link you have provided, that this is a maven project. You have to execute a maven package command, or maven install, so that the jar file will be generated. 
With this jar follow the Bill's instructions, and add it as external library to your claspath.

When you do this, you will be able to invoke methods of that api.
Let us know if you need some help doing this in eclipse.

If your project is a maven project, you can solve dependencies problems just adding the dependency written on Readme file to your pom file.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most automatic way is to use something like *maven, ant, or gradle*, that will automatically download and put the jars in to your classpath if they are in the central repositories. For example,  in the maven configuration file(pom.xml) you can add this to the dependency list:

[VGet Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.axet/vget/1.1.23)

These build tools also allow you to add external jars if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If 
I would suggest you get familiar with Maven. At the bottom there is a Maven dependency you just have to include into your pom.xml, and then you can use the extension immediately.
Maven is a build platform which organizes your project in a technical way (convention over configuration, e.g. code is in /src/main/java, tests are in /src/test/java). The proper way is it to create a Maven project in Eclipse (you have to install the plugin and download Maven as well) and put the dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.axet</groupId>
  <artifactId>vget</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.23</version>
</dependency>
```

into your `<dependencies>` inside your pom.xml. After adding it, you project recognizes the additional package automatically.

Nobody tinkers by adding libraries manually. It's actually not professional to work without a build platform like Maven or Gradle.